# Cannot build android project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

The following error pops up during the build process

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist. GullyWars   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1794
```

My target device is androind 4.4 api 19 
Help!

**Update**
I change the output verbosity to diagnostic and got the error at the following line under the file Xamrin.common.targets.What does it mean?

```
<Touch Files="$(_PackagedResources)" />
```

*Solved*
I reverted back to my old code and started from scratch it works!

Comment: Error is pretty clear isnt it?

Comment: ?? in the sense ...sorry i am new to coding

Comment: i did google it and nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove "Obj" folder in project directory and try again.

Comment: thank you for the solution but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with some .axml file of your android project. May be you are using the resource which may not exist or there is some problem with property name or value in .axml file. May be a file name is not proper. Ex. It shouldn't contain "-" dash.

Please have a look in .axml file thoroughly to identify the issue.

Still if this doesn't help please try this : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs
and dig into the actual reason mentioned in the Build Output window.

Hope this may help you solve your issue.

[My Build Output - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIpch.png)

Comment: i did do the above but still am confused what exactly is the problem ...can you have a look at my edit

Comment: That didn't help me to understand. Would you upload some more info if you can see in the verbose? Also try to check if there are no any spelling mistake in any .axml file code or property or value.

Comment: I have edited my answer with attached screenshot. Please let me know if you see such detailed error output.